# Grapevine C# 4.1.1

Tags: c#, regex, rest, grapevine

I'm trying to use Grapevine to serve files from a directory on my hard drive. The url sent to request the file will end in a file extension, for example http://localhost:1234/contact.html.

I'm trying to catch the requests made with the Route

```
[RestRoute(HttpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, PathInfo = @".\w{2,4}\Z")]
```

yet it's not matching on anything. I've checked my regular expression syntax on a regular expression checker and it works.

Does Grapevine 4 still support regular expressions? Or is my path info wrong?

Thanks.

Sethmo

Comment: `@"\.\w{2,4}\Z"`

Comment: Your RegX does not match your example url... Use https://regex101.com or similar to check whether your RegX match your data.

Comment: Thanks @LeonardoSeccia for the website. I didn't realise I was looking for a pattern that would look like this http://localhost:1234/.html. Fixed it to look for the entire path 
    [\/webapp\/]*[\/][\w]+\.\w{2,4}\Z

Comment: Apologies [\/webapp\/]*[\w]+.\w{2,4}\Z

Comment: After more wrangling [\/webapp\/]*[\.\w{2,4}]*\.\w{2,4}\Z. This matches all resources (webapp)*/<file>.<ext> and (webapp)*/<file>.<xxx>.<ext>. So, "webapp/angular.min.js", i"ndex,html", "style.css"...etc.

Comment: An easier way to serve files would be to use the `PublicFolder` class here: https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine/blob/v4.1.1.0/src/Grapevine/Server/PublicFolder.cs

Comment: `server.PublicFolders.Add(new PublicFolder("path/to/folder"));`